# How to get the client Object in the launchfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord Bot which needs sharding now. I created a file named "**botlaunch.js**", which I start from the console (`pm2 start botlaunch.js`). In this file is all stuff you need for sharding.

**Here is how my `botlaunch.js` looks like:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const settings = require('./settings.json');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const shardingManager = new Discord.ShardingManager('./lenoxbot.js',
        {
            token: settings.token
        });


    shardingManager.spawn('auto', 500).then(() => {
        console.log(chalk.green(`[ShardManager] Started ${shardingManager.totalShards} shards`));
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I need to access the client object after this code. I tried it with the following function but this **doesn't work** either. No errors or something like this, it only **returns undefined** for everything I request, doesn't matter what:

```
function exec(script) {
            let requestId = 0;
            const currentRequestId = requestId++;

            process.send({ cmd: 'exec', script: script, reqId: currentRequestId });

            const promiseExec = new Promise(resolve => {
                _promiseQueue[currentRequestId] = resolve;
            });
            const promiseTimer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    reject('Promise timed out before completion @ LenoxBotLauncher/exec');
                }, 60 * 1000);
                _promiseQueue.delete(currentRequestId);
            });

            return Promise.race([promiseExec, promiseTimer]);
        }
```

Do you have any solutions on how I can use the client under the code of my `botlaunch.js`?

Comment: What are you needing / trying to do with the client?

Comment: I need everything. All methods and properties @PLASMAchicken . I need the client for my website/dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ShardingManager#broadcastEval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=broadcastEval) if you want to obviously eval something, if you need some properties use [`ShardingManager#fetchClientValues()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=fetchClientValues) like:

```
shardingManager.fetchClientValues('guilds.size')
.then(results => {
    console.log(`${results.reduce((prev, guildCount) => prev + guildCount, 0)} total guilds`);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

If you want to broadcastEval/fetchClientValues from inside the Bot you can use `client.shard.fetchClientValues()`/`client.shard.broadcastEval()`

There is also a nice guide about it here: https://discordjs.guide/sharding/#broadcasteval

---

Another way would be to use 2 Clients instead of the ShardingManager like:

```
const client1 = new Discord.Client({ shardId: 0, shardCount: 2});
const client2 = new Discord.Client({ shardId: 1, shardCount: 2});
```

> This would mean that the bot will run in 1 process only and this might cause performance issues.

Comment: Yes I know this, but broadcastEval executes a script on all shards which I don't want because this isn't very performance friendly

Comment: `fetchClientValues()` would be the other options, otherwise I added another way, but it isn't really gonna be performace friendly either.

Comment: The problem is that you can just get properties with `fetchClientValues()`, I want to use methods too.